# How can I propagate the failure to the caller from an invoked script in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using jenkins to drive a powershell script. The script is build.ps1. In the Jenkins pipeline I specify

```
powershell './build.ps1'
```

I also tried

```
powershell './build.ps1; exit $LastExitCode'
```

I have a typo in my build.ps1, or I also get build failures, but Jenkins marks it as success anyway. The reason is that errors are apparently not propagated from the build.ps1 execution to the powershell spawned by jenkins. $LastExitCode is always zero. I verified this in a regular PS prompt with a broken script

```
./broken.ps1; echo $LastExitCode
```

gives zero even if test.ps1 throws an error.

I also tried to invoke with &. Same effect.

Comment: `./broken.ps1; $?`

Comment: Mathias, do you mean `./broken.ps1; $$`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen gives True

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your Build.ps1

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
#
# YOUR CODE
#
trap{
    echo "Error while building, error: $($Error[0] | select *)"
    exit 1
}
```

That should trap all errors, and exit with an error code 1.

Also if you can add a screenshot of your Jenkins config when you call the script, just to be sure I think it is what it is.

Hope it helps, good luck.